# android webview call javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i hava call webview setJavaScripEnable(true) but still hava no effect

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://ticket-account.pia.jp/pia/digipoke/list.do");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('login_id')[0].value='qqq'");
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: check my update ans

Comment: Hello kitt please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**i have same issue inmy app try**

try this

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


        }
    });

webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

        }
    });
    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.clearHistory();
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: how define MyCustomChromeClient

Comment: the js code have effect, but the webview will start the new empty page show "qqq"， i want to put the text in "login_id" element

Comment: you should load your url

Answer (score 0):

**Trt this one my friend**

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call javascript code from WebView, then you call `mWebview.load("javascript:")` then WebView will reload to an empty page, so you should try call `evaluateJavascript()`